# React history.push auto redirect

Tags: reactjs

I have implement a function to navigate to new screen when click a button in using media list in react bootstrap, but that function automatically called when screen is loading,

this is my code

```
 function News() {
    
    const history = useHistory()
    const [eventData, setEventdata] = useState('');
    const [MemberOffer, setMemberOffer] = useState('');
    const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [Loading2, setLoading2] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {

        getDatafromserver()
        getallmemebroffers()
        Logincheck()


    }, []);

    async function getDatafromserver() {
        console.log("inside getDatafromserver funcation")
        try {
            await fetch('http://124.43.17.60:4000/getallevent')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((json) => setEventdata(json.Rows))
                .catch((error) => alert('Please check your network'))
                .finally(() => setLoading(false))


            console.log("rana data", eventData)
            console.log("loding....", Loading)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error when get data from server")
        }
    }
    async function getallmemebroffers() {
        console.log("inside memebr offer funcation")
        try {
            await fetch('http://124.43.17.60:4000/memoffers')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((json) => setMemberOffer(json.news))
                .catch((error) => alert('Please check your network'))
                .finally(() => setLoading2(false))



            console.log("Member offers", MemberOffer)
            console.log("loding....", Loading2)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error when get data from server")
        }
    }



    const Logincheck = () => {
        console.log("inside login check")
        try {
            Axios.get("http://124.43.17.60:4000/loging_check")

                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("res cookie", response)
                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("No internet")
        }

    }

    function editNews(){
        history.push('/admin/edit-news')
    }

   

    return (
        <div className='home' >
            <br></br>
            <Card style={{ height: 'auto' }} >
                {/* memebr offer */}
                <Card.Header style={{ borderColor: 'white', fontSize: '30px', fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Bold' }}>Tech News</Card.Header>
                {Loading2 ? <Loader type="Circles" color="#00BFFF" height={80} width={80} /> : (
                    <div>
                        {MemberOffer.map((object, index) => (
                            // <p key={index.id}>{object.event_name}</p>
                            <Card.Body >
                                <ul className="list-unstyled" style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}>
                                    <Media as="li">
                                        <img
                                            width={72}
                                            height={72}
                                            className="mr-3"
                                            src={object.offer_image}
                                            alt="Generic placeholder"
                                        />
                                        <Media.Body style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>
                                            <h5 style={{ fontSize: '20px', fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Bold' }}>{object.offer_name}</h5>
                                            <p style={{ fontSize: '15px', fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Medium', color: '#707070' }}>
                                                {object.offer_content}
                                            </p>
                                        </Media.Body>
                                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={editNews()}>Edit</Button>
                                        
                                    </Media>
                                    <br></br>
                                </ul>
                            </Card.Body>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )}
            </Card>
           
        </div >
    )
}

export default News
```

when I'm reload the page this editNews() function already called and navigate to EditNews page without click the Edit button. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong with in this code and please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call the function in onClick. This should work.

```
 <Button variant="primary" onClick={editNews}>Edit</Button>
```